# How to create an NSIndexPath from an int?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Error message:

> cast of 'int' to "NSIndexPath *' is disallowed with ARC

Code:

```
NSInteger CurrentIndex;

[self tableView:(UITableView *)horizontalTableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)int_CurrentIndex];
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: If you cast an integer to an object, that will crash anyway...

Comment: @Deepak R Why dont you accept answer ?

Answer (score 83):

You can't cast an `int` variable to an `NSIndexPath` directly. But you can make an `NSIndexPath` from an `int` variable.

You need a `section` index and `row` index to make an `NSIndexPath`. If your `UITableView` has only one `section` then:

**Objective-C**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0];
```

**Swift**

```
let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowIndex, inSection: 0)
```

**Swift 4**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 0)
```

Comment: Glad to helped you.... One more thing it is okay if you dont know how to make `NSIndexPath` from `int` but seems to very bad you're trying to convert an `int` into an object type....!!

Answer (score 4):

`Swift 3.0`

```
let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0)
```